# How to succesfully implement a OnPostExecute method inside my doInBackground method?

Tags: android

Mentioned below is my JSONTask.java class:

```
public class JSONTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,String> {


public TextView tvData;

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    BufferedReader reader=null;
    HttpURLConnection connection= null;
    try {
        URL url =new URL(params[0]);
        connection= (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.connect();

        InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        String line="";
        while ((line=reader.readLine())!=null)
        {
            buffer.append(line);
        }

        return buffer.toString();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        if (connection != null) {
            connection.disconnect();
        }

        try {
            if (reader != null)
            {
                reader.close();
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    tvData.setText(result);
}
```

}

My app crashes when this item is called upon and i get the following errors in the logcat:" Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference" at .fragment.JSONTask.onPostExecute(JSONTask.java:63). It is pointing to the OnPostExecute method .

I am very new to programming and have been stuck here for a while.please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem as it semms is that your TextView is null. Maybe, you don'set this field from fragment. 
Pr, you create this asynctask in fragment's on create and it fails right away so quick that view isn't inflated yet. Try to surround it by try-catch and see in debugger if your textview is null

Comment: I might be totally wrong cause I  am just learning, but is this right? : `protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        try {
            if (tvData != null)
            {
                tvData.setText(result);
            }
        }
        catch (NullPointerException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return;`

Comment: Yes, see in debugger if textvew is set on task creation and if textviewbis null

Answer (score 1):

This is a normal NullPointerException. Your TextView tvData has not been initialized before.

Comment: If you could please give me a hint of how to do it?

Comment: not sure, you solved the issue. The TextView is usually taken from the layout. If you are inside an Activity, you would have in your `onCreate()` something like `tvData = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textData)` while `textData` is the id inside your layout. This is the basic concept of Android. So if you are not familiar with this, you should first start with some basic tutorials before trying to understand AsyncTask.